# Is there a way to know when the replaceState function of vuex store is called?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using `vuex-presistedstate` in my project. In the source code on github the plugin calls `store.replaceState` to hydrate store from storage. Is there a way to know when the store hydrates?

Comment: Did you try it via Vue Dev Tools? (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: I want to listen to it in the code..

Comment: So maybe you want to use rehydrated function

Comment: ?? Is there any hook available in either vuex or vuex-persistedstore for the same

Comment: On a second thought I can just subscribe to mutations in my use case but I wanna know if it can be done with a hook or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vuex-presistedstate` plugin has a configuration option called `rehydrated` that allows you to pass a function that will be called immediately after `replaceState`. If you only care about calls to `replaceState` from that plugin then that should fit your needs nicely.

I don't believe the store itself provides a 'hook' for when `replaceState` is called. The method `replaceState` is implemented here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e0126533301febf66072f1865cf9a77778cf2176/src/store.js#L183

As you can see from the code it doesn't do much. Even subscribers registered using `subscribe` aren't called. However, you could potentially use `watch` to register a watcher on a specific property within the state and use that to detect when the state is replaced:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Of course you'd need to be careful to structure things so that only the calls to `replaceState` trigger the watcher, which may get fiddly.

A further alternative would be to patch/override the `replaceState` method. Replace it with your own method that calls out to the original, giving you a hook point for any extra functionality you might need.

I've attempted to demonstrate all of the above in the example below:

```js
// Can't use localStorage in an SO snippet...
const fakeStorage = {
  vuex: `{"flag": {}, "number": ${Math.random()}}`
}

const storage = {
  getItem (key) {
    return fakeStorage[key]
  },
  
  setItem (key, value) {
    fakeStorage[key] = value
  },
  
  removeItem (key) {
    delete fakeStorage[key]
  }
}

// Override replaceState with our own version
class StoreOverride extends Vuex.Store {
  replaceState (...args) {
    super.replaceState(...args)
    console.log('replaceState called')
  }
}

const store = new StoreOverride({
  state: {
    flag: {},
    number: 0
  },
  
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      rehydrated () {
        console.log('rehydrated called')
      },
      
      storage
    })
  ]
})

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('store.subscribe called (will not happen for replaceState)')
})

store.watch(state => state.flag, () => {
  console.log('store.watch called')
})

console.log('creating Vue instance')

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  methods: {
    onReplace () {
      // The property 'number' is changed so we can see something happen
      this.$store.replaceState({
        flag: {},
        number: this.$store.state.number + 1
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex-persistedstate@2.7.0/dist/vuex-persistedstate.umd.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="onReplace">Replace</button>
  <p>{{ $store.state.number }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try rewrite `store.replaceState`:

```js
import store from './your/path/to/store'
// ...
store.replaceState = (fn => (...params) => {
  console.log('do something before replaceState called')
  fn.apply(store, params)
  console.log('do something after replaceState called')
})(store.replaceState)
```

In this way, you can watch not only `replaceState` but any methods on `store` instance if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a smart way of doing it

Comment: There's a potential difficulty doing this with `vuex-presistedstate` or other plugins because they can call `replaceState` before you have chance to replace it with your own version. It is possible to patch `replaceState` but I believe you'd have to do it at the prototype level to get in early enough.